# Compilation window that shows errors

Tags: external-command

The way I compile now is by calling make. A batch window pops up. Instead, I want the output to be in shown directly in Vim, just like Syntastic does it. Also, the errors inside should be navigable. Thanks!

Comment: See `:help :make`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `:make | copen` (for horizontal split)  or

`:make | vert copen`for vertical split

It opens a new window in vim to show the list of errors.

Comment: If this answer helps you, please click on the checkmark ! 